# What are the limits to Planet Master's "planet" powers?

Tags: dc

This guy, Irving Norbet,

[image: Irving Norbet as Planet Master]

Can he use all the powers of the planets in the Milky Way or is he limited to certain planetary super attacks. Like, for example, could he crush someone with Jupiter's gravity or freeze someone with Pluto's ice or use the powers of various weather effects of planets.

How much of the planets can Planet Master use?

Is there a specific listed amount of planetary attacks in which the Planet Master uses in any forms of media, comics, TV anything?

Comment: I checked Wikipedia but it only said he "has planetary powers" and doesn't say what specific powers he has

Comment: You included an image of Irving Norbet as Planet Master but he only ever appears in one issue as Planet Master as far as I'm aware. Edward Burke, his assistant, appears in a few issues as Planet Master but I'm not sure how well explained his powers are. Irving Norbet again does appear a couple of times in _The Brave and the Bold_ TV series. Are you restricting this to just Irving or Edward as well?

Comment: Both characters would be preferable but either one or the other is acceptable

Answer (score 4):

Irving Norbet as Planet Master only really appears in *Detective Comics Vol. 1* #296. However, we do get to see a few of his suits in that issue and what their powers are:

#### Mercury Suit

Spouts fire jets from the gloves and the suit itself, can envelop itself in flames and melt steel. It is so inspired because Mercury is one of the hottest planets being so close to the Sun.

[image: Page showing Planet Master's Mercury suit enveloped in flames] [image: Page showing Planet Master's Mercury suit shooting fire]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

#### Venus Suit

The Venus Suit creates a mist via clouds of steam so that Planet Master can steal things undetected and confuse people.

[image: Panels showing the Venus suit in action]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

#### Mars Suit

The Mars Suit is underexplained but from context it probably lets Planet Master breathe underwater and gives him other benefits from being underwater.

[image: Panel showing the Mars Suit]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

### Jupiter Suit

The Jupiter Suit works a bit differently to how you imagined it would, instead of increasing gravity on people it makes things bigger through a ray on the helmet.

[image: Panel showing the Jupiter Suit make pistols massive] [image: Page showing the Jupiter Suit in action]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

#### Saturn Suit

The last suit of his we see is the Saturn Suit which has floating flying discs he uses to attack people. He can also fly in this suit.

[image: Page showing the Saturn Suit's rings in action] [image: Page showing the Saturn Suit flying]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

---

Irving does again appear in the *Batman: The Brave and the Bold* cartoon TV series. His first appearance is in the "Aquaman's Outrageous Adventure!" episode in the "Plague of the Planet Master" section. Here his suit contains all of his planetary powers in one suit rather than an individual suit per planet. He uses the *"strength of Jupiter"*:

[image: Strength of Jupiter power shown with a shockwave into the ground]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

He then has the *"speed of Mercury"* making him pretty fast, probably not Flash standard but he does travel incredibly quickly. And then moves onto the *"cool of Pluto"* which appears to be similar to his Mercury Suit from the comics where he blasts a jet of "ice" out of the suit.

[image: Cool of Pluto shown freezing a shield]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

Aquaman shows up and he then demonstrates *"the power of the rings of Saturn"* which appears that he can "pick up" rocks levitate them around him and they start spinning. From there they move outwards decimating stuff in their path.

[image: Rings of Saturn power shown "starting up"]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

We then get a nice joke about not wanting to see the *"power of Uranus"*! I'm not quite sure what power he is using, Aquaman makes a comet pun so it could just be a comet power, but we see him "bring" rocks to himself which he merges into a giant ball and then throws it at our heroes.

[image: Giant ball power thing]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

That's pretty much all we see of his powers in that episode. We do see him again but he only appears as a background character in "A Bat Divided!" and as far as I can tell all he does is fist fight off screen so we don't see his powers.

---

To be as complete as possible we see Edward Burke as Planet Master a couple of times though mostly in *Outsiders Vol. 1* #21 and #22. In #21 we only get a very brief glimpse of him but he does use the *"heat of Mercury"* to melt steel. His powers here seem to be similar to those in *Batman: The Brave and the Bold*.

[image: Panel showing Planet Master using the heat of Mercury]
<sub>*Click image to enlarge.*</sub>

We get a bit more of a look into his powers in #22 but we only see the cold of Pluto and the heat of Mercury again. Although interestingly enough he believes the heat of Mercury could engulf the whole planet.

[image: Panel showing the cold of Pluto powers] [image: Panel showing the heat of Mercury powers]
<sub>*Click images to enlarge.*</sub>

Lastly, there is a small section on Planet Master *Who's Who: Update '87 Vol. 1* #5 as a member of Strike Force Kobra as he appears in *Outsiders Vol. 1* as shown above. It doesn't really give much detail but does state the following:

> *Planet Master*, a scientist whose uniforms enable him to simulate the conditions of other planets; for example, the freezing cold of the planet Pluto.

Comment: Odd that he doesn't seem to have an Earth suit.

Comment: @Jeeped The comic indicates he skips Earth due to how he came to be Planet Master so he only has other planets for inspiration as his suits.

Comment: @Jeeped: the Earth suit enables him to do things with the power of an average human. I've got one.